# disk usage script if under 90% dont email me

Tags: scripting

I have the basic command below, but I don't want an E-mail if disk usage is not over 90% - some type of else if statement possibly.

```
df -Ph | sed s/%//g | awk '{ if($5 > 90) print $0;}' | mail -s Disk Space Alert On $(hostname) douglas.hayes@whatever.org
```

Comment: If using Linux, this functionality is already a small part of `auditd`, with configuration such as percent of disk free in `/etc/audit/auditd.conf`.

Comment: That's a problem with "one-liners" is that it's difficult to insert intervening steps into the algorithm.  Start by breaking your script into multiple lines, using variables to capture the values you need, and so on.  Once you have the data in a variable, you can create an if/then/else to decide whether the value in the variable requires action or not.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to take your command and cobble this together:

```
df -Ph | awk 'int($5) > 90 {print $0; rc=1}; END {exit rc}' || mail -s "Disk Space Alert On $(hostname)" douglas.hayes@whatever.org
```

I got rid of `sed` as it should not be needed with `awk`.  In the `awk` statement, I am setting a non-zero return code if it finds any listed partitions over 90%, then only sending an email if the return was non-zero.

The only caveat I could think of is that `awk` could fail with an error and you would still get an email, but maybe that is desirable notification.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
if [ $(LC_ALL=C df / | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1 | cut -d' ' -f12) -gt 90 ]; then echo mail -s "Disk Space Alert On $(hostname)" douglas.hayes@whatever.org; fi
```

- `df` gives different output depending on the locale, which is why I prefixed it with `LC_ALL=C`. Alternatives to `C` are `POSIX`, `en_US.UTF-8` or other configured locales for your system.
- Replace the `/` in `df /` with the path to where the partition you want to check is mounted.
- `-gt` is a flag that stands for "greater than".